# Why this game appears to have 2 solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, game-theory

I'm trying to solve a two player zero sum game. After writing it in normal form I got the following matrix:

$$
\left( \begin{matrix}
5/4 & -1/4 \\
5/4 & -1 \\
2 & 2 \\
2 & 5/4 \\
-1 & -1/4\\
-1 & -1 \\
-1/4 & 2 \\
-1/4 & 5/4 \\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Eliminating the dominated rows I get:
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
5/4 & -1/4 \\
2 & 2 \\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

I try to find mixed strategies $\vec p$ and $\vec q$ for this matrix, such that:

$$
\sum_i p_i = 1 \\
\sum_i q_i = 1
$$

But then, I get the solutions:

$$
\vec p = (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) \\
\vec q = (3/2, -1/2)
$$

Which contradicts the condition I want to fulfill.

Solving this game with Sage I get two solutions:

$\vec p = (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), \vec q = (0, 1)$ and $\vec p = (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), \vec q = (1, 0)$

Can somebody explain me why I'm not getting the correct solution?

Comment: Are u sure you eliminated the rows correctly?

Comment: Ok, the final matrix was just (2 2). That explains everything :/

Comment: Exactly :P Does it turn out right now?

Comment: I guess it has 2 saddle points and then 2 different solutions?